# Python - Error scatter plotting with Matplotlib: Index out of range

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm very new to Python, and I have a CSV file with three columns. They represent a transmission time in milliseconds, signal amplitude, and FM radio frequency in kHz. There's a lot of lines, but they look something like this:

[image]

My task is to find out which radio frequency is generating random noise and which is a structured signal. For how to do this, I'm trying to first find the unique values in the frequency column of my data file (column 3) and then plot them individually to find the structured data. My guess is that the 71.231012 frequency is the white noise (it seemed less frequent in the file), and so I'm basically trying to plot both frequencies to see if my guess is somewhat correct.

So far, this is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplot
import numpy as np

file=open("data.csv", "r")
data=file.read()
data=data.replace(" ", ",")
data=data.split("\n")

xscatter=[]
yscatter=[]

for row in data:
    row=row.split(",")
    row[2]=float(row[2])
    if row[2] == 71.231012:
        xscatter.append(row[2])
        yscatter.append(row[1])

mplot.scatter(xscatter, yscatter, color="blue", marker="o")
mplot.show()
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
row[2]=float(row[2])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure why this is the case; I thought that, with the split, I would have three indexes per row (0,1,2). And because I'm so new to Python, I'm also not sure how accurate or efficient my code is at doing what I want, but it's a start. I'd greatly appreciate some help.

EDIT: Here is a sample of my output after splitting the file, before the for loop:

[image]

Comment: I see how you converted the data. I think that's where your mistake is, could you tell me what `print(data)` prints out?

Comment: Oh, also you're re-declaring variable `row`, you've used the variable `row` already in the for-loop, I prefer using a temporary variable to avoid confusion. (I don't really remember if that matters though)

Comment: Sure -- do you mean printing the data within the for loop or before? Before the split or after?

Comment: Before the for loop, after the split. :)

Comment: Sure, I've edited my original post and included a screenshot (it's an awful lot of output).

Comment: don't post images of your data. post your data

Answer (score 1):

The code `row=row.split(",")` sets the `row` variable to something like `['0.000000', '', '0.000000', '', '0.000000']`. Your code is giving index error because there are no index 2 from the string `''`.

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. My idea is to remove those annoying empty strings in the array by changing your `row=row.split(",")` to `row=row.split(",,")`, this will work perfectly.
2. Change your `data=data.replace(" ", ",")` to `data=data.replace("  ", ",")` (two whitespaces), that will also work perfectly.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately I still get an index out of range error.

Comment: @Garrett McClure I'm sorry to hear that, but do you have an extra newline at the end of your file?

Comment: It looks like it does (I originally had opened my file in Excel by default and didn't see it). When I opened it in a text editor, there was an extra line. I'll delete the line and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an input csv file like the following,

```
0,1.62435,7.61417
0,-0.611756,7.61417
0,-0.528172,71.231
0,-1.07297,71.231
0,0.865408,7.61417
0,-2.30154,7.61417
0,1.74481,7.61417
0,-0.761207,7.61417
0,0.319039,71.231
0,-0.24937,71.231
1,1.46211,71.231
1,-2.06014,7.61417
1,-0.322417,71.231
1,-0.384054,7.61417
1,1.13377,7.61417
1,-1.09989,71.231
1,-0.172428,71.231
1,-0.877858,7.61417
1,0.0422137,71.231
1,0.582815,71.231
```

You can read it in using `numpy.loadtxt` and plot it separated by frequency value by looping over the respective unique frequencies in the last column.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt("data/filename.csv", delimiter=",")

for freq in np.unique(data[:,2]):
    thisdata = data[data[:,2] == freq]
    plt.scatter(thisdata[:,0], thisdata[:,1], label="{}".format(freq))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```